# Cannot update msal to v4.51 on Xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to update MSAL 4.4 to MSAL 4.5.1 to fix an authentication issue on IOS : MSAL .NET on iOS 13 does not support system browser

- fixed in 4.5 release of MSAL. Issue now, is that I cannot update MSAL to 4.5

Error Message - when trying to update MSAL library:

The package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Drawing.Common.dll' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an issue w/Visual Studio when VS tries to upgrade the dependency. If you manually update to MSAL4.5.1 (by editing the csproj and the packages) it will work. The workaround is to move away from packages.config to PackageReference. Similar issue [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3531).